# why tomcat instance running by tomcat is only visible with localhost address not with my real network ip?

Tags: netbeans, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

I have netbeans 7.1.2 with tomcat 7 and a javaEE web application.
whenever I run the project from netbeans I only can see the running only on "localhost" not on any other ips or address such as "192.168.0.1"

how can I solve this problem?

my OS is ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: is 192.168.0.1 the ip address of the server that the app is installed?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your internet service provider might not have provided you with a global IP address, which is necessary to run your app on the internet.. To check if you have a global IP address, type `ipconfig` in command prompt and check all available IP addresses. You can contact your ISP to demand for a global IP address!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

In the File configuration **Httpd.conf** of Apache the line that serves (File of Connector) to Tomcat (Suppose in Windows):

```
Include ".../Tomcat/conf/auto/mod_jk.conf"
```

In the file **mod_jk.conf** maybe you have:

```
...
JkWorkersFile "...LocationOfYourWorkerFile..."
...
<VirtualHost localhost>
  ...
  ServerName localhost
  ...
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

Where **ajp13** is Tomcat worker defined in JkWorkersFile.

In the **JkWorkersFile** maybe you have:

```
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
# END workers.properties
```

Change to in **mod_jk.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
  ...
  ServerName localhost
  ...
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case you are saying that not only works for localhost, but also works for all ip's through 80 port.